# Remap Control+Space to behave like Return (enter key), compatible with vim

Tags: keyboard, vim

### How can I map Control_L + Space to Return?

preferably to be done with xmodmap.

I did trying to search for some answers but with no success.

My current solution is:
 ~/.Xmodmap

 `keycode  65 = space Return space 
 keycode  37 = Control_L Mode_switch Control_L`

~/.vimrc:

`inoremap <C-@> <CR>
cnoremap <C-@> <CR>
nnoremap <C-@> <CR>`

any solutions for change ctrl+space to behave like return( a.k.a The 'Enter' key) for the entire system?

Comment: That depends on the terminal/emulator used.  You could use xterm's translation resource to map control+space to return.  Other terminals differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some more research and have tried several different solutions, finally settled with one solutions which doesn't result in any delay or inconsistency. The solution below not only work for terminal but also other applications.

---

## Tools that I used:

*xdotool*, *xbindkeys*

#### (1) install *xdotool* and *xbindkeys*:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install xdotool
$ sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

#### (2) create xbindkey config file:

```
$ xbindkeys -d > ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

#### (3) remap Ctrl-Space in xbindkeysrc

```
"xset r off; xdotool keyup --window 0 space key --clearmodifiers --window 0 KP_Enter; xset r on"
   m:0x14 + c:65
   Control+Mod2 + space
```

#### (4) Kill current xbindkeys

I'm not sure why this is necessary but simply source xbindkeysrc doesn't replace current config. Thus, you have to kill xbindkeys

```
$ killall xbindkeys
$ xbindkeys -f ~/.xbindkeysrc
```

#### All set.

#### Bonus

map ctrl+~ to be /

```
"xset r off; xdotool keyup --window 0 grave key --clearmodifiers --window 0 slash; xset r on"
   m:0x14 + c:49
   Control+Mod2 + grave
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, that works.  Especially the `xdotool` trick of "keyup" is needed for it to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

[`xmodmap`](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.2/doc/xmodmap.1.html) will not take you to your goal.  The closest in its repertoire is this paragraph (reformatted to show the points):

**`keycode`** *NUMBER* **`=`** *KEYSYMNAME* ...

The list of *keysyms* is assigned to the indicated *keycode* (which may be specified in decimal, hex or octal and can be determined by running the [xev](http://www.xfree86.org/current/xev.1.html) program). Up to eight keysyms may be attached to a key, however the last four are not used in any major X server implementation.

- The first *keysym* is used when no modifier key is pressed in conjunction with this key,
- the second with `Shift`,
- the third when the `Mode_switch` key is used with this key and
- the fourth when both the `Mode_switch` and `Shift` keys are used.

That is, you could use xmodmap to associate some existing key with the shift-modifier.  However, you want that *existing key* to be <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> which does not correspond to a key you are likely to find on your keyboard—nor is there an existing *keysym* for it.  Rather, you may use <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> on occasion to generate an ASCII NUL, but it is so rarely used that there is no standard key on the keyboard for this.

However - both `xterm` and `urxvt` can be configured, separately and with different methods to distinguish <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>.  With `xterm`, that would be the `translations` resource, while `urxvt` has a `keysym.sym` resource.

If you are using `xmodmap`, likely you are using either [`xterm`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html) or [`rxvt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rxvt) (perhaps [`urxvt`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt)).  With other terminals, people tend to wade into the [`xkb` morass](http://www.charvolant.org/~doug/xkb/xkb.pdf).  But reviewing the documentation, it seems to have the same limitation as `xmodmap` (essentially more of the same thing, no genuinely *new* capability in this area).